# Disk busy is close to 100% and iowait is 0,0% on SunOS, how can it be possible?

Tags: solaris, performance, io

During monitoring of SunOS5.10 machine I noticed strange behavior:

1. Disk busy is close to 100%
2. Disk waiting time is 0,0%

Primary purpose of this machine is running application server on jvm. This situation happens when server is under heavy load and clients connections are randomly rejected. If problem is IO related probably IO wait time should be more than 0,0%. I can't see any other bottlenecks on the machine: cpu, ram are plenty and network interfaces are utilized under 5%. At the time of disk saturation system writes around of 0,5 MB of data per second and reads almost none.

Data is dumped with `sarmon`, and `iostat -x` is used for live monitoring. Sample `iostat` output:

```
extended  device  statistics
device  r/s    w/s    kr/s  kw/s  wait  actv  svc_t  %w  %b
sd0,a   0.0    0.4    0.0    6.2   0.0   0.0   11.5   0   0
sd0,b   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0   0   0
sd0,c   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0   0   0
sd0,f   0.0    0.2    0.0    1.6   0.0   0.0   13.9   0   0
sd0,g   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0    0.0   0   0
sd0,h   0.0  111.6    0.0  519.9   0.0   1.0    8.9   0  94
```

Statistics are taken at the OS level, so measurements should be correct. Is it possible on the application level to reliably detect disk saturation and reduce load accordingly?

What are possible scenarios when such situation occurs?

I have also used dd to test write speed of the disk with the following results:

```
time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output bs=512 count=2048k"
2097152+0 records in
2097152+0 records out
real 0m3.250s
user 0m0.627s
sys  0m2.622s
```

Comment: What command(s) do you use? Please post a sample output.

Comment: Data is dumped with sarmon, and iostat -x is used for live monitoring. Sample iostat output: extended device statistics
device    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv  svc_t  %w  %b
sd0,a     0.0    0.4    0.0    6.2  0.0  0.0   11.5   0   0
sd0,b     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0
sd0,c     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0
sd0,f     0.0    0.2    0.0    1.6  0.0  0.0   13.9   0   0
sd0,g     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0
sd0,h     0.0  111.6    0.0  519.9  0.0  1.0    8.9   0  94

Comment: I have also used dd to test write speed of the disk with the following results:time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output bs=512 count=2048k"
2097152+0 records in
2097152+0 records out

real    0m3.250s
user    0m0.627s
sys     0m2.622s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There looks to be a single thread writing a little bit more than 4KB about 111 times per second. This is sufficient to keep your disk 100% busy (111 iops * 9 ms service time = 1 second of service per second = 100%). As there are no other processes writing on that disk (that partition actually), the wait queue is empty, all requests are processed immediately.

There is then nothing special or strange in your workload, the disk is the bottleneck.

To get better performance, you might pick a faster disk or an SSD, or use use an array of disk that distribute writes, or tune the application for it to use larger blocks, or increase the cache size.

Your `dd` test is pointless, you are not measuring the disk performance but essentially the cache one, especially on Solaris where `/tmp` is likely to be backed by virtual memory, `tmpfs` being the default for that file system.

Comment: What would be the recommended way to test actual disk performance?

Comment: I would suggest you to read these articles to get a better understanding of file system performance under Solaris : http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/05/11/file-system-latency-part-1/ http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/05/13/file-system-latency-part-2/ http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/05/18/file-system-latency-part-3/ http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/05/24/file-system-latency-part-4/ http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/06/03/file-system-latency-part-5/

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O, a program is firing up requests for I/O, but does not wait on them. However it can still accept and process the I/O responses once they come.

Comment: How do you think this link answers the OP question ?

Comment: the question was "What are possible scenarios when such situation occurs?"

Comment: Asynchronous I/Os cannot be a valid explanation of zero iowait. That might be at best the opposite.

Comment: oh, you mean because there will still be shadow processes waiting for the blocks? That could be, I did not think so far, sorry.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with shadow processes waiting for blocks. There are only writes in the OP case anyway. The iowait metric is reporting the percentage of time during while the wait queue is not empty. This queue is not empty when there at least an I/O is ready to be processed but the disk cannot handle it immediately being busy doing something else. Enabling asynchronous I/Os will increase the risk for that queue to be filled, not the opposite.